# Looping the list

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I have a problem with looping a list of songs. I have a `List<String> _songList` which contains songs paths (loaded correctly, checked). So I thought that there is an event which will tell me "Ok I stopped playing the song, I'm ready to play the next one". In `NAudio` it should be `StoppedEventArgs` added to `WaveOutEvent.PlaybackStopped`. But in my case it doesn't play another song, neither the same again. Here is my code:

```
public void Play_List(String _playlistName)
{
    try
    {
        if (_songList.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!_paused)
            {
                _currentList = _playlistName;
                PrimaryOutputStream =
                    new MediaFoundationReader(_songList[_songIndex]);
                VolumeStream = new WaveChannel32(PrimaryOutputStream);
                VolumeStream.PadWithZeroes = false;

                Player.Init(VolumeStream);
                Player.PlaybackStopped +=
                    new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(RepeatMode);
            }
            Player.Play();

            _paused = false;
            _isPlaying = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}

public void RepeatMode(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (_songList.Count > 0 && _currentSong != null)
        {
            _paused = false;
            switch (_repeatMode)
            {
                case 1:     //Repeat one song
                    Play_List(_currentList);
                    break;
                case 2:     //Repeat whole list
                    NextSong();
                    Play_List(_currentList);
                    MessageBox.Show("Changed song");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Of course I set _repeatMode to 2 for list and 1 for one song.
I was searching the internet for help but found nothing. Anyone?

Comment: Where's the code for `NextSong`?

Comment: Have you placed a break inside of the event to test if the event is being called? - maybe the event IS being called and the problem lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see anything in your code which sets a value to the _currentSong. Probably, it is coming as null and your code is not getting executed.

```
if (_songList.Count > 0 && _currentSong != null)
```